# About Function and Parameter

Tags: javascript, parameters

New to Javascript, still confused about parameter

Here are some codes:

```
var people = [{                                             
  name: 'Casey',                               
  rate: 60
},
{
  name: 'Camille',
  rate: 80
},
{
  name: 'Gordon',
  rate: 75
},
{
  name: 'Nigel',
  rate: 120
}
];

function priceRange(person) {                        
return (person.rate >= 65) && (person.rate <= 90); 
 };

var results = [];                              
results = people.filter(priceRange);
```

I know this is a very basic question, but I just want to know the parameter "person".How did the computer know the parameter "person" is coming from the object "people"?

Comment: Does the [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) documentation help you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Data structures :

- `[....]` this is an array
- `{attr1:'val1', attr2: 'val2',. ...}` this is a literal object.

↪ `people` is an ARRAY of literal object**s** , and each object has two attributes (keys) : name & rate.

## Functional Programming:

Since `people` is an array, Array class provides a set of methods ,namely `filter()` which accepts as first argument : FUNCTION .

`filter()` will run the function  (1ˢᵗ argument of `filter`) for each item , then if it returns `true`, it accepts the element , and vice versa .

Let's take , an example more simple than what you have : let's take `an Array of digits`

```js
const arrayOfDigits = [23, 400 , 99, 4, 222];


function exceed100(element) {
  return element > 100;
}

console.log(
  arrayOfDigits.filter(exceed100)
)
```

example above filters all digits less or equal to 100.and it keep only digits exceeds 100.

Comment: Thanks, I understand how does the filter() works, I just more confuse about the question of transferring parameter. I know person is the parameter in the priceRange() function, but how did "person" came from and why did  person.name equals to people.name?

Comment: Keep the following callback's rule in your mind : You can choose any  name for argument (`person`, `element`, ...`item`, however you should keep the order (`person` is the 1ˢᵗ arg, `index` is the 2ⁿᵈ arg.. so on)

Answer (score 0):

The `Array.prototype.filter()` function loops through the array that it was called on, and calls the callback function with each element as an argument. So when you use `people.filter(priceRange)`, the `filter()` function calls `priceRange` with each element of `people`. The code of `filter()`  is something like this (I've simplified it greatly just to show how this part works):

```
function filter(callback) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (callback(this[i])) {
            result.push(this[i]); // This gets person from people
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```